# Completion handler VS holding a reference: the most appropriate for this scenario in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

I have the following scenario: an object `A` creates an object `B` that should perform some operations depending on a user's choice. `A` is delegate of `B`. `A` does not hold a reference to the choice the user has made (represented by another object `C`), but it knows it in the method where it creates `B`, and it needs to know which the choice was when the object `B` finishes its task and notifies of that by calling the corresponding protocol method that `A` implements.

The first solution I think of for this scenario is to have a reference in `A` for the choice `C`, and access it in the protocol method implementation that `B` calls when it finishes. But maybe it would be better and more "swifty" to handle such choice `C` by passing a completion handler, and thus avoiding holding a reference in `A` until `B` finishes.

What do you think about this second solution (to pass a closure as completion handler to `B`)? Would it be more appropriate than the first solution (holding a reference in `A`)?

In such case, how should I implement that solution? Should `B` have a reference for the closure to be called as completion handler?

**EDIT:** Some additional information of my scenario:

- `A` does not exactly have a property `B`, it pushes it into a navigation controller.
- `A` does not always need to know about `C` when `B` finishes, it depends on the task requested to `B`
- `A` only needs to know about `C` once `B` (depending on the task performed by `B`, as said before) has finished to update some data.
- `A` only needs to know (depending on the task performed by `B`, as said before) only one `C` at once

Answer (score 1):

In short, in your ownership hierarchy `A` owns `B`, both classes use `C` and you want to know whether `C` should be owned by `A` or `B`.

You have 3 basic options:

1. Both `A` and `B` own `C`.

That means that `A` saves `C` into a property, passes it to `B` during initialization and `B` also saves `C` to a property.

2. `A` owns `C`.

That means that `A` saves `C` into a property and doesn't pass it to `B` at all. `B` asks for it using a delegate method when it needs it (`A` serves as data source for `B`).

3. `B` owns `C`.

That means `A` passes `C` directly to `B`, `B` saves it to a property with a public getter and when `A` needs `C`, it reads it from `B`.

(Note your idea is a variant of the third option).

Note that neither of the three options has anything to do with *swiftiness*, it's purely an architecture choice and there is no "best" solution. If you want to decide, you have to consider the states of your application, for example:

1. Should `C` exist in `A` even after `B` is destroyed? If yes, don't use the 3rd option.
2. Does `A` handle multiple `B` or `C` at once? Then don't use the second option.
3. Is `C` mutable or immutable? Is it a value or class type? If it's a value type, you cannot use the first option.

In most situations all 3 options above will be fine and the choice will be a personal decision that won't affect the quality of your code if you keep it consistent across your application.

**EDIT:**

It seems to me that the 3rd option is really the most appropiate solution for your situation. However, as I said before, there is not one "best" solution

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I should give some further details about my scenario, I'm going to edit my question.